# Error when using MobileFirst 8 through F5 LoadBalancer

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere, mobilefirst-server

We have a MobileFirst 8 cluster running through an F5 LoadBalancer.
The Pools on the F5 connect to the default secure ports of the JVM in Websphere. The pools come up and register fine.

I have set the mfp.admin.proxy.host domain name of access (resolves to the Virtual Server on the F5
               mfp.admin.proxy.port 443
               mfp.admin.proxy.protocol https

We are getting this error when starting the servers in websphere.

[26/03/19 10:40:59:936 GMT] 000000b6 AdminMXBeanIm I   Config service/Live Update is not yet ready
[26/03/19 10:41:02:030 GMT] 000000c3 RetryExec     I org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://FQDN of Virtual server on F5:443: Connection reset
[26/03/19 10:41:02:030 GMT] 000000c3 RetryExec     I org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute Retrying request to {s}->https://FQDN of Virtual server on F5:443
[26/03/19 10:41:02:092 GMT] 000000c3 RetryExec     I org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://FQDN of Virtual server on F5:443: Connection reset
[26/03/19 10:41:02:092 GMT] 000000c3 RetryExec     I org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute Retrying request to {s}->https://FQDN of Virtual server on F5:443
[26/03/19 10:41:02:154 GMT] 000000c3 RetryExec     I org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://FQDN of Virtual server on F5:443: Connection reset
[26/03/19 10:41:02:154 GMT] 000000c3 RetryExec     I org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute Retrying request to {s}->https://FQDN of Virtual server on F5:443

The servers start fine when using a HTTP server but I cant find any documentation for using MobileFirst with a Loadbalancer to help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The log says:

```
(java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://FQDN of Virtual server on F5:443: Connection reset
```

which means F5 is resetting the connection request that comes in. Is F5 configured to reject outbound requests from the JVM?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but no it isnt. Have you any other thoughts?

Comment: Well , you mention that server starts fine when its a HTTP server in place, but not with F5. This suggests that requests are either not getting to F5 or getting rejected when they do. What does tracing/debugging F5 show? Are the requests reaching it?

Answer (score 0):

Enable HTTP logs, So that you can trace the excat problem,
`<accessLogging filepath="${server.output.dir}/logs/http_defaultEndpoint_access.log"/>`